# How can I remove all cells of a type in UITableView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would like to be able to remove all cells of a certain type that I assign from a tableview.  How could I accomplish this.  I also have a switch that sets up cell owner attributes and would like to use this to assign the type.

Comment: What is *type*?

Comment: You should wirte more detail that you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly remove cells with a particular identifier. You need to have some way to know which cells have what reuse identifier.

This is the way I would achieve such a thing:

1. Suppose I have to list students in the list with different majors.
2. I would introduce an enum in the student class that will list all the major courses.
3. Now I will assign a particular value from the enum to a student with a particular major.
4. I will use that enum variable to draw different cells assigning them a reuse identifier.
5. Now when I want to filter the students of a particular subject, I will filter the array of students with a given enum value and refresh the tableview.
6. This will remove all the cells with a particular identifier automatically.

Comment: HAK speaks truth. Your thinking is backwards. Cells display a data model. Using different cell types for different entries in your data model is a display detail. What's important is that your data model contains different types of entries. You want to filter that underlying data, and then when you tell your table to reload, it will display the filtered data and some cells will be removed.